# Build regex that separates file names in a string

Tags: regex

Given a string of file names like this: 'New Text Document (2).txt New Text Document (3).txt New Text Document (4).txt New Text Document.txt\n'
I would like to create a list with the following elements:
['New Text Document (2).txt', 'New Text Document (3).txt', 'New Text Document (4).txt', 'New Text Document.txt']
It seems that using regexes are the answer.
Any ideas?

Comment: How can you tell, if the user created a file with a name `New Text Document (2).txt New Text Document (3).txt`, or two files with name `New Text Document (2).txt` and `New Text Document (3).txt`? I suggest to change the system that put all those filenames together in one string to use appropriate escaping and separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the expression you are looking for:

```
\ ?(.+?\.\w+)
```

Of course you need to use that in your language of choice to get the captured matches